# Shared storage between Ubuntu VM servers

Tags: ubuntu, shared-storage

I am setting up worker servers on Digital Ocean. These Ubuntu servers need to access files in a common storage area.

What process or program do you recommend for storing files on a shared folder between multiple servers? Copying items to Amazon S3 or attached storage is not an option. The servers are able to "talk" to each other across the private network. My thought is to make a dedicated server for just file storage and then symlink the other servers to the shared folder on the dedicated server.

Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) is good for this purpose.

Comment: @ewwhite Thank you for the tip. After reading about NFS, this sounds like a viable solution. I found this tutorial link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Comment: I found this NFS article on Digital Ocean's website: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-12-04